# How to run 10 processes at a time from a list of 1000 processes in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

```
 def get_url(url):
     # conditions
import multiprocessing
    threads = []  
    thread = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_url,args=(url))
    threads.append(thread)

    for st in threads:
        st.start()
```

Now i want to execute 10 requests at a time, once those 10 are completed. Pick other 10 and so on. I was going through the documentation but i haven't found any use case. I am using this module for the first time. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you're looking for a Python equivalent to GNU Parallel or xjobs?  Sounds like you need [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool).

Comment: @TobySpeight  I am looking for GNU parallel. I tried pool but with apply_async, But haven't got any luck. Code Snippet : 'pool = mpool.ThreadPool(20)
for index, data in df.iterrows():
    a=pool.apply_async(get_url, args=(url ))
    a.get()'

Comment: `ThreadPool` is not the same as `multiprocessing.Pool`!